# NameError in class - calling a previously defined variable

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm new to OOP, and I'm trying to write a simple class below, but I keep getting a NameError

```
class rng(object):
    _rand_nums = [6,3,2,1]
    _p = [0.1,2,0.7,0.4]

    if any(i >= 1 for i in _p):
        _norm = sum(_p)
        _p = [i/_norm for i in _p]
```

When I try to run this, I get:

```
<ipython-input-116-097f599a4ce0> in <listcomp>(.0)
     15     if any(i >= 1 for i in _p):
     16         _norm = sum(_p)
---> 17         _p = [i/_norm for i in _p]

NameError: name '_norm' is not defined
```

What's wrong with my code? I thought I defined `_norm` fine.

Comment: Why do you use a class at all?

Comment: I have a several methods later in `rng`, but they're not pertinent to the issue here now. I can't even instantiate the class before I fix this error